# How To surround a string in Quotation Marks in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have a label which is bound to some text in my view model like so:

```
<Label VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Note, StringFormat='&quot;{0}&quot;'}" Style="{StaticResource ListItemSubTitleStyleDefault}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" FontAttributes="Italic"/>
```

And I am trying to get the note to be surrounded in quotation marks like so

> "I am a Note"

looking at some `WPF` answers it suggested using the following in the `StringFormat` property `'&quot;{0}&quot;'`

But this doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to surround a `Labels` text in quotation marks in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: And how it doesn't work, throws, displays that verbatim, ignores quots?

Comment: @Evk Just ignores the quotes

Comment: Did you try escaping with backslash?

Comment: @slepz would that be `'\"{0}\"'`? - Just tried this code and causes a build error

Comment: not sure how to fix your problem in xaml, but you could use an IValueConverter on the binding and format the string in c#, which will allow the backslash escaping. Might be less efficient though.

Comment: Try set `'"{0}"'`. I guess you don't need a scape char in xaml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've seen, Xamarin.Forms is different from WPF for this case. For Xamarin, do this:

`<Label VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Note, StringFormat='{}&quot;{0}&quot;'}" .../>`

In order to prevent the runtime from ignoring the double quotes, the first double quote either has to be escaped (as above), or it can't immediately follow the single quote (see below).

So for example, throwing in a space in between works as well:

`<Label VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Note, StringFormat=' &quot;{0}&quot;'}" .../>`

With this latter solution, there will be at least one character rendered before the double quote.

Comment: Thanks, what about single quotes? 

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it should work to use &apos; instead of &quot;

Comment: I tested and It didn't work for me but thanks for the suggestion 

Answer (score 0):

On the code from your ViewModel you can also do this:

```
string _note;
public string Note => string.Format("\"{0}\"", _note);
```

I hope this helps.